# Remove rows with same first column and min second column

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a two column list. The first column are subject numbers, the second session numbers (i.e. when the subject comes in the second time, the session number is 2, and so forth for every visit).

```
SubMasterList = [6004 1; 6004 2; 6008 1; 6008 2; 6010 1; 6012 1; 6012 2; 6012 3]
```

I would like `SubMasterList` to only contain 1 row of the subject with the greatest session number (column 2). So as to appear to be:

```
SubMasterList = [6004 2; 6008 2; 6010 1; 6012 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sortrows`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) after which you extract indices from that array using the second output of [`unique`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)

```
SubMasterList = [6004 1; 6004 2; 6008 1; 6008 2; 6010 1; 6012 1; 6012 2; 6012 3];
tmp = sortrows(SubMasterList,-2); %sort, with descending order to ensure the highest number is on top
[~,idx,~]=unique(tmp(:,1)); %extract indices
Result = tmp(idx,:) %index the sorted array to obtain the result

Result =
        6004           2
        6008           2
        6010           1
        6012           3
```

Comment: This can be further improved by removing the `flipud` function and using `-2` instead of `2` in `sortrows` function  which will sort the rows of second column in the descending order. ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I was already looking for the `sort`-like `'descending'` option; I didn't know this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you want is almost the definition of [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) :-) Just use [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get labels based on the first column of your matrix, and pass that as first input to `accumarray`:

```
[x, ~, u] = unique(SubMasterList(:,1));
y = accumarray(u, SubMasterList(:,2), [], @max);
result = [x y];
```

Comment: @Adriaan `accumarray` is not a loop in disguise in the same sense as `arrayfun` is. This should be faster than `for` or `arrayfun`. But who knows nowadays, with loops getting faster with JIT...

Comment: Oh interesting. I thought `accumarray` did the looping as well. Never too old to learn I guess

Comment: @Adriaan Internally of course it must do so. But it has a name for being fast, unlike `arrayfun`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not efficient as @Adriaan 's answer:

```
A = [6004 1; 6004 2; 6008 1; 6008 2; 6010 1; 6012 1; 6012 2; 6012 3];

[C,~,ic] = unique(A(:,1));
B = A(:,2);
for ii=1:max(ic)
    D(ii,1) = max(B(ic==ii));
end
SubMasterList = [C D]; 


SubMasterList =

        6004           2
        6008           2
        6010           1
        6012           3
```

Comment: Interesting to see you used all outputs of `unique` except the one I got. Good answer.

Comment: I should time the difference, but it's too much bedtime now ;) I guess it'll make a noticeable difference only when the amount of rows exceeds some 10,000 or so. Your code might actually be more understandable than all my flip-flopping of arrays. Point of perfection: initialise `D`. You know how big it's going to be (i.e. the size of `C`) and that'll be lots faster with large arrays.